# MySQL unique key only where another key contains a specific value

Tags: mysql, mysql5

I have a table which contains meta data for users. There are 4 fields...

```
`ID`,`meta_name`,`meta_value`,`user_id`
```

I want to store emails in this table. Naturally these must be unique. However I want to store other data in this table as well, where the data does not need to be unique. Is there any way I can restrict `'meta_value'` to be unique, only if `'meta_name'` is equal to 'email'?

Comment: directly from db? you have to create a stored procedure to add into this table, when meta_name is email you do a table lock, check for email then unlock the table

Comment: No, and that's precisely the reason NOT to use such a design. If the number of `meta_name` possible values is small, define them as columns (then placing a constraint would be trivial); otherwise think of storing them in different tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By means of MySQL's contraints - no.

However you can use insert/update trigger that verifies uniqueness of the data and forbids illegal operations.

Here is a draft of insert trigger (You can play with it here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c9e3):

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER VerifyInsert BEFORE INSERT ON YourTestTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM YourTestTable
WHERE YourTestTable.meta_name = 'EMail' AND YourTestTable.meta_value = NEW.meta_value
AND NEW.meta_name = YourTestTable.meta_name) > 0 THEN

  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'VerifyInsertFailed';

END IF;


END;

//
```

Comment: Kuba, can unique constraints be added in such a way that it meets the requirements I outlined above? (unique depending on another key)

Comment: No, as I said: "by means of MySQL's contraints - no".

Comment: Sorry, I muddled myself in reading your reply - I meant update triggers, not unique constraints.

Comment: Please take into account that `SIGNAL` is only available in MySQL > 5.5 or sth.

Answer (score 3):

With MySQL contraints it's impossible, without special tricks (like redundant column `unique_helper` with constant value for `meta_name`=`email` and random for each other + `UNIQUE` index for `unique_helper`+`meta_value`).

But you can use custom TRIGGER in innoDB tables: (rememeber to put `yourTable` name)

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerName
BEFORE INSERT ON yourTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.meta_name = 'email' AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable WHERE meta_name='email' AND meta_value=NEW.meta_value)
  THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Duplicate email';
  END IF;
END;
```